# Can't add product images to WooCommerce products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm simply trying to upload a product image for each product on the "Edit Product" page on the WordPress backend.  However, there is no place to upload a product image.  How do I get the product image upload area to show up in Wordpress?

I have tried editing the single-product.php file but I don't really know where to start. I also tried adding a custom field to product page types which allowed me to create an area where product images can be added, but they don't show up in the actual place where product images are supposed to go.

I'm assuming the reason the ability to add product images is not available is because of some conflict with my custom theme. However, I cannot change themes.  I am able to edit the current theme, but I just don't know how to go about fixing this problem

Update: I temporarily changed the theme and the ability to add a product image became available. But, when I changed it back to my custom theme, that ability went away.  Any ideas of what in my custom theme could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is working if you choose another theme, it could be the case that the product image is the "featured image" in wordpress. With the featured image, you can set an image to your wordpress posts. Articles are just posts with a custom post type.

It could be possible, that your theme has not activated the featured image feature. You can do this by adding this line of code to the end of your **functions.php** of your theme:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

If this makes not show up the possiblity to add an image to a product, it could be a problem with the editor. Have you tried changing vom gutenberg to classic editor? Just to make sure, it is not a editor problem.

EDIT:

If you want to show your featured image in the product single page, you can do this with

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver! That worked.  I have been trying to fix that problem for weeks now.  Thank you!!!  One new problem I'm having is with the product gallery.  When I click an image in the gallery, it brings me to a black page that only has the gallery image in the middle of it.  Any clue how to fix this to be able to select a gallery image and it show up in place of the main product image?

Comment: @Katherine - Accept the answr if it worked for you - Ask the above comment as another question for getting fast and better solution.

Comment: Glad to help! Please mark my answer as the accepted answer. Your other problem sounds like you want to have a lightbox. If your image is linked to it's source, it appears on an empty black page. If you install a plugin like https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/easy-fancybox/ your image will be opened in a lightbox if you click on it